# Crystal Report - Generating multiple reports one PDF

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a DB of data as follows:

```
User a - cat data 1
User b - dog data 1
User c - cat data 1
User d - dog data 1
User a - mouse data 1
```

In normality, while printing a report, I would print 5 PDFs. However what I will like to do is that for "User a", I will like to print only 1 PDF, i.e., PDF page 1 will be "cat data 1",
page 2 will be "dog data 1", and page 3 will be "mouse data 1" as it does not make sense to send to the same user multiple PDFs.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Currently, this is my code:

```
_crAdviceRpt.Load("C:\Users\AdviceTemplate.rpt")
 _crAdviceRpt.SetParameterValue("Line1", strLine)

    outLocationFile = strArray(1) + "-" + "Account_Number" + ".pdf"
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\Store"
    CrExportOptions = _crAdviceRpt.ExportOptions
    With CrExportOptions
        .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
        .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
    End With
    _crAdviceRpt.Export()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're placing the data in the details section and that you're sending the data to the CR using a table I would try:

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Click on the Details section and select the "Section Expert" option.
3. Check the option "New Page After"

   [image]

Comment: if I am using an arraylist, how do i set that?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way is by creating a dataset in your VB Project, populate it with the data from the arraylist and then bind it to the CR so that it can be printed.